# Reading and displaying an image from a folder

Tags: c#, image, asp.net-mvc

I have a question concerning the correctness of the reading and displaying the image in ASP.NET Core MVC web application.

This is the way I am reading image names from a specific folder (I am using `IHostingEnvironment _hostingEnvironment` to get the `rootPath`):

```
   public class GetRandomImageForGalleryView : IGetRandomImageFromFolder
    {
        private string rootPath;
        public GetRandomImageForGalleryView(string rootPath)
        {
            this.rootPath = rootPath;
        }
        public string[] getImage()
        {
            return ReadPhotosFromDirectory();
        }
        private string[] ReadPhotosFromDirectory()
        {

            string[] fileLocations = Directory.GetFiles(rootPath+"\\lib\\Images\\Nature").Select(path => Path.GetFileName(path))
                                     .ToArray();
            return fileLocations;
        }
    }
```

And this is the way I am displaying them:

```
@model IGetRandomImageFromFolder
@{ 
    ViewBag.Title = "Gallery";
}
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        @{
            foreach (var item in Model.getImage())
            {  
                <img src="~/lib/Images/Nature/@item" style="max-width: 500px;">
            }
        }
    </div>
</div>
```

Basically I just replace the image name.

Is this a good way? If not, why? Any other remarks would be helpful as well.

Comment: I would simplify the GetImage() method as suggested by @svick and I would also avoid the method call from the Razor view, build the list of files in a controller and then pass it to the view rather.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could simplify your `getImage()` method pretty significantly to just:

```
public IEnumerable<string> GetImage() =>
    Directory.GetFiles(rootPath + @"\lib\Images\Nature").Select(Path.GetFileName);
```

Things I changed:

1. Changed capitalization to follow .Net naming guidelines.
2. Removed unnecessary method `ReadPhotosFromDirectory()`.
3. Removed unnecessary variable `fileLocations`.
4. Used verbatim string to avoid having to escape backslashes.
5. Used method group to delegate conversion instead of lambda.
6. Got rid of `ToArray()`, which didn't serve any purpose, and changed return type to `IEnumerable<string>`.
7. Used C# 6.0 expression bodied method.

Comment: Wow, that did not answer my question if it is a good way to display this way by passing in the image like that in the razor view, however you gave me a nice lesson to research. Yeah I am coming from Java background so naming is something I still will have to look around in .Net as well bunch of things I will look now differently at, big thanks :))

Comment: @vsarunov there is nothing wrong in using razor to display your images this way